# How do I stop Disqus page from coming up

Tags: ubuntu, popup, malware, disqus

Every now and again, a chrome page is opened up, that goes to the Disqus login page.

I do not want an account on Disqus, I have no interest in it.

I have performed the following steps.

xwininfo

```
$ xwininfo            

xwininfo: Please select the window about which you
          would like information by clicking the
          mouse in that window.

xwininfo: Window id: 0xc600003 "Log In | Disqus - Google Chrome"
(REDACTED DATA)
```

xprop

```
$ xprop -id 0xc600003    
(REDACTED DATA)
_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 1721880
(REDACTED DATA)
```

ps for window

```
$ ps -eaf | grep 1721880
username 1721880    5353  0 14:09 ?        00:00:19 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

ps for windows caller

```
$ ps -eaf | grep 5353   
username    5353    5054  5 Jun25 ?        02:35:04 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

Obviously, I can't stop the gnome-shell from running if I want a desktop, Whatever application is doing this is putting a popup on my desktop.

How do I identify the responsible application? I simple want to stop Disqus, even if that means uninstalling whatever application is putting a popup on my desktop.

Please help, thank you.